# Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void t_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        double anInteger;
        anInteger = Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text);
        anInteger = double.Parse(label1.Text);
        double val1;
        double val2;
        double answer;
        double previous_val;
        previous_val = Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text);
        previous_val = double.Parse(label1.Text);
        val1 = anInteger;
        val2 = ((((((previous_val ^ 1.001)) / 24) - ((previous_val / 24) / 60)) / 10));
        answer = val1 + val2;


        label1.Text = answer.ToString();
    }
```

I am getting the error "Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'" at the line:

```
val2 = ((((((previous_val ^ 1.001)) / 24) - ((previous_val / 24) / 60)) / 10));
```

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: As Al says, what you're doing makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve with the expression `previous_val ^ 1.001`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
Math.Pow(previous_val, 1.001);
```

will solve your problem. this is the way how to use powers in .net

Comment: Use powers in .Net, now he might just use `^` again for integers, yielding unexpected results ;)

Answer (score 7):

^ is bitwise operator XOR. It makes no sense on double type.

What was your intent?

Comment: So your solution to this error would be...? (I'm Guessing to convert everything to a decimal?)

Comment: Tell us what is your intent. What do you mean by writing previous^1.001 ?

Comment: Its all good, the answer below solved my problem. Previous value is the current value in the label.

Comment: I have been using C# for a very long time and never knew that ^ is XOR. Thanks for the info

Comment: Can you perform a bitwise XOR on doubles in c#?

Comment: @Xonatron: That is nonsense. There are no bits in double as you think of them.

Comment: @AlKepp, I understand what you are saying, but I also understand how the bits exist in a double (sign-bit, exponent, mantissa). My intent was to modify doubles on a bit-wise level, knowing what I am messing with.

Comment: That bit-based memory is just a concept from low level languages. In a higher level language, it doesn't exist. I mean on a conceptual level, in a higher level language like C#, memory of a program doesn't consist of bits. It consists of objects. I understand that if you used to program in C or assembler or something like that, this is hard to accept. :-)

Comment: I give you credit for being the only 'answer' at the moment that even addresses the misconception OP incurred in their intent with this question.  but this is not an answer; it is a comment. one that asserts a subjective sensibility argument on arbitrary reasoning; stating primitive value types in c# aren't to be conceptualized as bits and bytes because the `Type` inherits from object, is actually quite absurd, completely wrong even;  the value of `double` is allocated in memory (stack or heap) exactly how you would expect it to be, 128 bits, boxed or otherwise.  https://imgur.com/a/I7YhJjR

Comment: in the image I linked is a less arbitrary reasoning for not doing XOR with doubles.  Their values can be imprecise.  Having said that, XOR is common with streaming, block ciphers for cryptography.  It is definitely not a low level language, nor to be construed as having any basis on the size of the data structure.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking to raise a Value1 to the power of Value2

Use:

```
Math.Pow(Value1,Value2)
```

In your example:

```
Math.Pow(previous_val,1.001)
```